# How do I exit out of my switch statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

My attempt:

```js
const find = function (map, type) {

let location = [];

for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++){
        switch(true) {
            case (type === 'gold' && map[i][j] === 'R' ):
                location.push(j,i);
                break;
            case (type === 'silver' && (map[i][j] === 'S' || map[i][j] === 'R')):
                location.push(j,i);
                break;
            case (type === 'bronze' && (map[i][j] === 'S' || map[i][j] === 'R' || map[i][j] === 'M' ) ):
                location.push(j,i);
                break;
            default:
                return 'false';
                break;
        }
    }

}

return location;
};
console.log(find(
    [
        // COLUMNS ARE X
        // 0    1    2    3    4    5
        ['s', 'R', 's', 'S', 'n', 'M'], // 0 ROWS ARE Y
        ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'r', 'M'], // 1
        ['s', 'M', 's', 'R', 'r', 'm'], // 2
        ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'r', 'M'], // 3
        ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'r', 'M'], // 4
        ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S']  // 5
    ],
    'gold'
));
```

I'm basically traversing through a 2D array representing a map of minerals and returning the coordinates of the very first plot of land which matches the conditions in my switch statement by logging the indices into array location and returning it.

I have two primary issues:

How do I code it so that the loop is terminated as soon as the first plot of land which matches my case condition is found? Right now JS will continue to loop through the entire 2D array pushing in more coordinates which I don't wan't.

I want JS to simply return the string False if nothing is found. However, this seems to be happening even when the case statements evaluate to True. Just wondering if I have some sort of typo?

Answer (score 1):

A boolean value wouldn't be the ideal use-case for a switch statement -

`switch(true)` - the parameter should accept a variable. You're passing a constant variable. The variable should match the case statements.

The proper usage of `switch(bool)`, should really be

```
var myBool = getValue();
switch(myBool) {
  case true:
    console.log('true');
    break;
  case false:
    console.log('false');
    break;
```

For the logic, I'd suggest an `if/else` block

```
            if (type === 'gold' && map[i][j] === 'R' ){
              location.push(j,i);
            } else if (type === 'silver' && (map[i][j] === 'S' || map[i][j] === 'R')){
              location.push(j,i);
            } else if (type === 'bronze' && (map[i][j] === 'S' || map[i][j] === 'R' || map[i][j] === 'M' ) ) {
              location.push(j,i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return the array of indices by using a check.

```
const find = function(map, type) {
    for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
            if (type === 'gold' && map[i][j] === 'R' ||
                type === 'silver' && (map[i][j] === 'S' || map[i][j] === 'R') ||
                type === 'bronze' && (map[i][j] === 'S' || map[i][j] === 'R' || map[i][j] === 'M')
            ) {
                return [j, i];
            }
        }
    }
    return 'False';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The first your function hits `default` it simply returns `false` so you want to change that. Here a refactor using mostly your logic with a few changes to the switch case:

```
const find = (mapArr, type) => {
for (let i = 0; i < mapArr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mapArr[i].length; j++) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'gold': {
                if (mapArr[i][j] === 'R') return [j, i];
            }
            case 'silver': {
                if (mapArr[i][j] === 'S') {
                    return [j, i];
                }
            }   
            case 'bronze': {
                if (mapArr[i][j] === 'M') {
                    return [j, i];
                }
            }
            default: continue;
        }
    }

}
};
find(
    [
        // COLUMNS ARE X
        // 0    1    2    3    4    5
        ['s', 'R', 's', 'S', 'n', 'M'], // 0 ROWS ARE Y
        ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'r', 'M'], // 1
        ['s', 'M', 's', 'R', 'r', 'm'], // 2
        ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'r', 'M'], // 3
        ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'r', 'M'], // 4
        ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S']  // 5
    ],
    'bronze'
)
```

Answer (score -1):

this will return `false` if nothing is found using `switch` case:

```
find = function (map, type) {

  let location = [];
  let notFound = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++){  

        switch(true) {
          case (type === 'gold' && map[i][j] === 'R' ):
            location.push(j,i);
            break;

          case (type === 'silver' && (map[i][j] === 'S' || map[i][j] === 'R')):
            location.push(j,i);
            break;

          case (type === 'bronze' && (map[i][j] === 'S' || map[i][j] === 'R' || map[i][j] === 'M' ) ):
            location.push(j,i);
            break;
          default:
            notFound++;
        }
        if(location.length == i + 1) break;
      }

    }
  if(notFound == map.length) return false;
  return location;
};

console.log(find(
  [
    // COLUMNS ARE X
    // 0    1    2    3    4    5
    ['s', 'R', 's', 'S', 'n', 'M'], // 0 ROWS ARE Y
    ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'r', 'M'], // 1
    ['s', 'M', 's', 'R', 'r', 'm'], // 2
    ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'r', 'M'], // 3
    ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'r', 'M'], // 4
    ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S']  // 5
  ],
  'gold'
));
```